# Use Ruby to Truncate duplicate patterns in an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

**SITE ADMIN: WOULD YOU PLEASE REMOVE THIS POST?**

For example, I have

```
tt = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and I would like to slim it down to

```
tt_out = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

also I'd like to know when does the repetition begins and ends, hence I'd like to have the following tip

```
tip = '0','1.','.5','6.','.11','12.','.15','16.','.20'
```

Comment: You can remove duplicate entries from an array in Ruby with the uniq Method http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq

Comment: yes, but how can you do the second part of the question. I'd appreciate if you could advise on that!

Comment: Also, please note that I'd like to find re-occurrence sequence not just to find uniq entries.

Comment: The format you propose for `tip` will result in complicated parsing down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tt = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
tip = []
tt_out = tt.map.with_index{|t, i|
  start_range = (i==0 || tt[i-1] != tt[i])
  end_range = (tt[i+1] != tt[i])
  if start_range && end_range
    tip << "#{i}"
  elsif start_range
    tip << "#{i}."
  elsif end_range
    tip << ".#{i}"
  end
  t if start_range || end_range
}.compact

tip
=> ["0", "1.", ".5", "6.", ".11", "12.", ".15", "16.", ".20"]
tt_out
=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

P.S: You've got an error in your example, the last element of tip should be '.20'